# Java Library for reading and writing DDS textures

Tags: java, directx, dds-format

I am looking for a Java Library for reading and writing images in DDS format. Preferably all subformats (DXT1c, DXT1a, DXT3, DXT5, ...)

Googling hasn't brought up any results for me yet, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following links will help you. All these links are related to reading and converting DDS image.

https://github.com/Dahie/DDS-Utils

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip43.html?page=1

http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-Java/1.0/Beta2/

https://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Java-3D/ferox-gl/com/ferox/util/texture/loader/DDSTexture.java.htm

http://code.google.com/p/java-dds/

http://nuicode.svnrepository.com/svn/community-earth/CommunityEarth%20-%20NBProject/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/formats/dds/DDSConverter.java

http://www.guyford.co.uk/showpage.php?id=122&page=Creating_a_Texture_from_a_Buffered_Image_in_JOGL

Answer (score 1):

Sure you have googled? A quick search for "dds image java" gets me:

- http://code.google.com/p/java-dds/
- http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/doc/com/jme/image/util/DDSLoader.DDSReader.html
- http://devblog.ctdp.net/2009/12/dds-utilities-released/

Comment: jMonkeyEngine changed their docs page: [DDSLoader](https://javadoc.jmonkeyengine.org/v3.x/com/jme3/texture/plugins/DDSLoader.html)